# Android Google maps fragment in RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-viewholder

How can I get to GoogleMap from RecyclerView.ViewHolder

I have:

```
public class MapRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
 public MapRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
 }
}
```

xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android.support.v7.cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android.support.v7.cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
android.support.v7.cardview:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner"
android.support.v7.cardview:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:tag="maps"

        android:id="@+id/map_view_fragment" tools:context=".Map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

adapter:

```
public class MapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
{


 public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder mh;


        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.map_row, viewGroup, false);
        mh = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder)new PodatkiZaMapRowHolder(v);

        return mh;
    }

 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder RowHolder, int polozaj) {

        MapRowHolder mapRowHolder = (MapRowHolder)RowHolder;


    }


}
```

It displays map correctly. And it is zoomed out to whole earth. And positioned to 0,0 in center.

How can I get maps fragment (in ViewHolder)? I would like to move camera to other location (I can do this after I get GoogleMap object) How and where should I get GoogleMap object?

If I use MapView instead map fragment It works, but doesn't refresh map. Map refreshes after I click on map a few times.
Regards, Ales

Comment: From the XML coded you posted, you use cardview, so do your mapfragment is not inside a recyclerview. Also what do you mean by not refresh? You can check out the documentation of recyclerview here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Problem is how to get maps fragment. If I have TextView in xml (xml for row) I can get it in RecyclerView.ViewHolder as findViewById(R.id.my_text); and then I can set value as RowHolder.myText.setText("test"); How can I do this with map fragment?

Comment: By not refresh, I mean it is in some kind pause mode. It show blured map, then when I click, it update map to better image, after another click it updates some labels, and if I click more times, it updates al the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I ended up is to dynamically add SupportMapFragment to the FrameLayout inside item layout. You just have to create additional FrameLayout with unique id.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/car_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Peugeot 407 2.0 HDI"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

    <include layout="@layout/ride_item_summary" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

adapter:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 1:
            if (first) {
                ... //check if polyline is not null, init other views

                    FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout) ((RideItemHolder) holder).mMapLayout;
                    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(mContext);
                    frame.setId(1010101); //you have to set unique id

                    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 170, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
                    frame.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    view.addView(frame);

                    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
                    options.liteMode(true);
                    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);

                    //Create the the class that implements OnMapReadyCallback and set up your map
                    mapFrag.getMapAsync(new MapReadyCallback());

                    FragmentManager fm = fragment.getChildFragmentManager();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(frame.getId(), mapFrag).commit();

                    first = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            ...

private class MapReadyCallback implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        drawMap(googleMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your instance of "fragment"?

Comment: everytime your scroll the recyclerview, the method "view.addView(frame);" called many times?